# How can I make the Video Settings on Windows Media Player take effect?

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-media-player, display-settings

I have

- Windows 7
- WMP 12
- the latest version of K-Lite Mega
- newly upgraded video card

When I slide the pointer in *Hue*, *Saturation*, *Brightness*, and/or *Contrast*, the pointer stays where it is, but no effects happen whatsoever, even after I close the **Enhancements > Video Settings** dialogue box.

I tried sliding one at a time to the extreme left and right, to see if any perceptible change happens. Nothing.

The videos are too dark on Windows Media Player, but the color is just fine on Media Player Classic 6 and VLC. But I prefer WMP because it doesn't have the choppy playback and other issues of VLC (now using 2.2.4, but have had the same problems since pre-VLC 2x) and MPC 6.

The other Enhancement settings like *Play Speed* and *SRS WOW Effects* work though. Only the **Video Settings** have no effect whatever position the pointer is at.

Answer (score 0):

What's the file format of the videos that you tried? It's possible that the Video Settings only have an effect on formats like WMV and MP4.